# Java home error when building android native app from sencha touch 2.0

Tags: sencha-touch

This is my first application building for android native app from sencha. I have followed the sencha getting started video tutorial, but am getting some errors.

The error says that:

> -compile: ""D:android-sdk-windows/tools/android" create project --target android-7 --name GetStarted --activity STActivity --path "c:\wamp\www\GS\build\native/" --package  com.mycompany.myAppID" Could
>   not run ant with error: 1 Failed to package application [ERROR] BUILD
>   FAILED D:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:602: The following
>   error occurred whi le executing this line:
>   D:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:622: Unable to find a javac
>   compiler;
>
> com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.

Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK?

It is currently set to "`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`"

It says that `java_home error`, but I have already set the java_home like this:

> variable name :- JAVA_HOME variable value:- c:/programes
>   files/java/jdk 1.6/bin

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a environment variable JAVA_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME=c:/Program Files/java/jdk 1.6
```

and in your PATH variable

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

All this in OS Win XP/7.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You *might have* mispelled "program files" in your path

Change

```
 c:/programes files/java/jdk 1.6/bin
```

to

```
c:/Program Files/java/jdk 1.6/bin
```

Comment: The builder says it is set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7". It seems that the builder ignores the primary value of JAVA_HOME.